# How to configure apache tomcat server to the oracle database

Tags: node.js, database, reactjs, oracle, apache

I have created an application based upon node JS and react JS, here I am using the oracle database for the data with node JS. The issue here is that the application is able to run but it does not able to make any API calls because all  the data that needed to be handled is on the oracle database, I think the application does not able to establish a connection to the oracle database server. 
I am new to this whole deployment stuff and this my first web based project.

Here is the configuration code for the database connectivity:

```
module.exports = {
   database:{
    user          : 'user_name',
    password      : 'pass',
    connectString : 'something'
   },
   jwtSecretKey: "jmvhDlong......."
};
```

I am using two oracle database server, one for storing the user details and the second to fetch the details:

Code for the user database server:

```
module.exports = {
   database:{
    user          : 'user_name',
    password      : 'pass',
    connectString : 'something'
   },
   jwtSecretKey: "jmvhDlong......."
};
```

Code for the database server from which the details need to be fetched:

```
module.exports = {
    database:{
     user          : 'user_name',
     password      : 'pass',
     connectString : 'something'
    },
 };
```

And don't worry about the user, password and connectstring those are correct.

I need to bypass the apache server configuration so that the application can able to connect to the oracle database and able to make the API calls.

Comment: What has apache to do with node and oracle?

Comment: I don't know I have deployed the application and given the node server.js, you can able to access the UI part of the application, but whenvever you login and something related to the data fethcing from the database, the API calls gets failed

Comment: From this I can understand that the application does not able to establish the connection to the oracle database, and the project is working on the local system only after deployment on the apache server, it does not able to make connection to the databse

Comment: So I think its pretty much related to the apache

Comment: So it works with apache on local system, but not with other deployment method?

Comment: no, I am able to use the application from my pc alone by running it my pc alone, then it is working. But I need to deploy it on the server so that everyone can access it, but after deployment it is not working

Comment: I think it is because of the oracle database client installation.

Comment: @Anurag You're not making it easy to help you. You started with an issue related to Tomcat but never said why. Now you say you think it's the Instant Client, but again you don't say why. We need details to help you. Error messages are very helpful.

Comment: There are no error messages just API call failed, and I included the oracle instant client because if it is not installed properly the backend will not able to make a connection to the oracle database and why apache because in order to work with databases you need to configure the configuration file such as httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to use appache as a user to login to an oracle-db?

there is a parameter for ms-sql, called integratedSecurity (=true), and you can set a software as a user in db, so you can acces ms-sql with tomcat.

if you want to do something like this, i think this isnt possible, my knowlegde is 2years old, dont know if something changed meanwhile.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I think I have found the answer maybe it is because of oracle database client installation.

Comment: aah, okay, so you are step before. yeah you need a client. and depending on your db, you cal also define tns-names for multiple server.

i worked with oracle thinclient 11/12.
maybe you also need to define some enviromentan variables.

Comment: hey can you help me out with this, I have installed the oracle instant client and also the glibc-2.14 and also setup the LD_LIBRARY_PATH but still  my API calls are getting failed.